# Creating an archive of all jars and source jars for a multi-module project

Tags: maven-2

I'm building a Maven project which has half a dozen modules.

I'm fine with importing it myself using either Maven or Ivy, but other teams would like to use those jars as well, but their practice is to commit the jars and source jars to version control.

I'd like to generate a zip/tar assembly of all modules and their sources which they can use however they like.

I've read [Maven Assembly Plugin: Including Module Binaries](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/examples/multimodule/module-binary-inclusion-simple.html) but I'm shy of using it because:

1. The [linked FAQ entry](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/examples/multimodule/faq.html#module-binaries) returns a 404;
2. I need to manually specify all modules.

Is there an alternative?

---

*Update*: I've tried using the built-in assembly descriptors

```
 mvn assembly:assembly -DprojectModulesOnly=true
 mvn assembly:assembly
```

and both failed with

```
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] BUILD ERROR
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Failed to create assembly: Error creating assembly archive bin: You must set at least one file.
```

right after all the module builds have run.

Comment: I have this exact same problem (and exactly 1 year, 2 days later the linked FAQ still is 404)

Answer (score 4):

I think you're on the right lines, the moduleSets options of the assembly plugin handles what you're after.

If you're looking for some useful documentation, the [Module Selection](http://www.sonatype.com/books/maven-book/reference/assemblies-sect-modulesets.html#assemblies-sect-module-selection) section of the Maven book covers it quite thoroughly, including how to configure includes and excludes, handle binaries and sources, and exclude external dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem, for me, the solution was NOT put `/` at the beginning of your `<fileset><directory>`

If you do that will work on Windows, not on Unix/Linux!

```
<fileSet>
  <directory>src/main/</directory>
  <outputDirectory></outputDirectory>
  <includes>
    <include>VERSION</include>
  </includes>
</fileSet>
```

works whereas

```
<fileSet>
  <directory>/src/main/</directory>
  <outputDirectory></outputDirectory>
  <includes>
    <include>VERSION</include>
  </includes>
</fileSet>
```

causes

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-assembly-plugin:2.3:single (execution-pluggin-assembly) on project test3: Failed to create assembly: Error creating assembly archive assembly: You must set at least one file. -> [Help 1]

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the [How to use assembly:assembly using predefined descriptor ids](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/howto.html). I think the `bin` and `src` [pre-defined descriptor files](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/descriptor.html) are what you need.

Comment: It looks like the assemby-plugin could not find anything to assemble. Could you please provide the maven-assembly-plugin configuration section and the assembly descriptor?

Comment: The first link is dead.

Answer (score -4):

Sounds like you need a build-server of some kind. I was at JavaZone 2009 this week and looked at Hudson CI http://hudson-ci.org/

The server will create the artifacts you or other teams can use/download.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm actually using Hudson, but I'd like to do this with Maven, since I did not find a way to generate a zip of all jars from Hudson.