# Packaging several subprojects in several different jars

Tags: maven, jar, package

I want to package my maven in one big ZIP containing all the jars of my different sub-projects. The ZIP thing can be done afterwards.
Here is my project architecture:

How can I do to package my application in this way :
. Subproject-1.jar
. Subproject-2.jar

So far, I only managed to generate one big jar with everything inside, I tried this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8292752/maven-multi-module-project-copying-all-package-jars-from-submodules-into-par) (add a maven-dependency-plugin:copy in either the parent or the children), but I couldn't manage to do something even remotely good.
When I try to package one children this is what I get :

> [ERROR] The build could not read 1 project - [Help 1]
>
> [ERROR] The project SubProject-1:[unknown-version] (Project/SubProject-1/pom.xml) has 1 error
>
> [ERROR] Non-resolvable parent POM: Failure to find parent:pom:1.0-SNAPSHOT in file://Project/libs was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of in-project has elapsed or updates are forced and 'parent.relativePath' points at wrong local POM @ line 3, column 11 -> [Help 2]

Thanks for your time

Comment: Please show the full pom files your projects and the directory strucutre you have and how and from where you called Maven.

Comment: @I'm sorry, I can't post it because "Your post seems to contain code that is not formatted as code". Thank you, I solved my problem anyway while thinking at why the post was invalid.