# Parent pom maven package not copying subfolder Quarkus microservice JAR files

Tags: java, maven, microservices, pom.xml, quarkus

Hello currently I have a parent git repo that houses two separate microservices written in Quarkus. For the ease of use within a CI/CD in the parent root folder I created a pom.xml that when I run a `mvn package` I want to be able to copy it into the `parent/target/` path.

So the folder structure for instance is like this currently.

```
parent
  target
  pom.xml
  /microservice1
    - microservice1.jar
  /microservice2
    - microservice2.jar
```

but I want it to look like

```
parent
  target
  - microservice1.jar
  - microservice2.jar
  pom.xml
  /microservice1
  /microservice2
```

Since the parent folder/git repo doesn't have a pom.xml I generated one and this is what it looks like and I tried to use the `maven-dependency-plugin` suggestion that I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8292752/maven-multi-module-project-copying-all-package-jars-from-submodules-into-par/8293209#8293209)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>com.example</groupId>
  <artifactId>parent-service</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

  <packaging>pom</packaging>
  <modules>
      <module>microservice1</module>
      <module>microservice2</module>
  </modules>

  <name>parent-service</name>
  <!-- FIXME change it to the project's website -->
  <url>http://www.example.com</url>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.7</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.7</maven.compiler.target>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.11</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
          <executions>
            <execution>             
              <id>copy-artifact</id>
              <phase>package</phase>
              <goals>
                <goal>copy</goal>
              </goals>
              <configuration>
                <artifactItems>
                    <artifactItem>
                      <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
                      <artifactId>${project.artifactId}</artifactId>
                      <version>${project.version}</version>
                      <type>${project.packaging}</type>
                    </artifactItem>
                </artifactItems>
                <!--<outputDirectory>../Main/target/dependencies</outputDirectory>-->  
                <!--CHANGE IS HERE -->
                <outputDirectory>target</outputDirectory>
              </configuration>
            </execution>
          </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
</project>
```

After running a `mvn package` at the parent folder the individual microservices are still packaging their own respective jars into `microservice/target/` folders. Another weird interaction seems to be that the parent will just package it's own pom into it's own target/ folder. I could post the sub-microservices pom.xml files but those are quite long. What am I doing wrong? Did the way I create the pom not work well?

Comment: I am not sure this is a good idea. Why not let the CI/CD process read the files from where Maven places them?

Comment: @JFabianMeier hey, I'm not handling the CI/CD pipeline but I've been told that it is so they can re-use the same CI/CD pipeline without having the user or whoever juggle with even more input variables. As in this minor example the parent directory only has two currently but can grow with even more microservices. Of course having all the microservices as a separate repo would make it easier but for maintainability this is how they want it.

Comment: Actually, I would try with the maven antrun plugin which allows you to easily move files on the directory level.